# fewer constant-time iterations take more time - c++ compiler dependence?

Tags: c++, g++, profiling

I wanted to demonstrate in my class that sampling with pre-ordered probabilities can improve execution time. In the code below, the `sample()` function is the working horse. The same random variable distribution is stored in two forms: unsorted probabilities (arrays `p` and `x`), and sorted probabilities (arrays `p1` and `x1`) - see the `main()` function. The counter variable counts for loop iterations.

The results: with `(p,x)` input, `sample()` takes twice as mush time as with `(p1, x1)` but the elapsed execution time is the same or even longer. I tried  g++ 7.4.0 compiler at my home laptop Kubuntu 18.04, and I tried different g++ versions at ( wandbox dot org ) with basically same results.

I don't understand how it's possible: fewer constant-time iterations take same to longer time.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

inline double runif(){return rand()/double(RAND_MAX);}

double sample(double* p, double* x, int N, double u, unsigned long* count)
{
    int k;
    for(k=0; (k<N) && (u>p[k]); k++, (*count)++)
        u -= p[k];
    return x[k];
}

double sample_alias(double* p, double* x, int N, double u)
{
    double u1 = u * N;
    int K = floor(u1);
    double u2 = u1 - K;
    return (u2<p[K]) ? *(x+2*K) : *(x+2*K+1);
}


int main()
{
    double p[] = {0.2, 0.05, 0.125, 0.5, 0.125};
    double x[] = {0,   -3,   1,     -2,  3};

    double p1[] = {0.5, 0.2, 0.125, 0.125, 0.05};
    double x1[] = {-2,   0,    3,    1,    -3};

    double sum;
    unsigned long counter;

#define NN 4000000
    double *u;
    u = (double*)calloc(NN, sizeof(double));
    if(u==NULL) perror("Not enough mem!");
    srand(5647892);
    for (int i=0; i<NN; i++) u[i]=runif();

    cout << "Test 1 (unsorted)" << endl;
    sum=0.0; counter = 0;
    auto begt = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(int i=0; i<NN; i++) sum+=sample(p,x,5,u[i], &counter);
    auto endt = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = endt - begt;
    cout<<sum/double(NN)<<endl<<"Run took "<<elapsed.count()<<", total loop: "<< counter<<endl;

    cout << "Test 1 (sorted)" << endl;
    sum=0.0; counter = 0;
    begt = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(int i=0; i<NN; i++) sum+=sample(p1,x1,5,u[i],&counter);
    endt = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    elapsed = endt - begt;
    cout<<sum/double(NN)<<endl<<"Run took "<<elapsed.count()<<", total loop: "<< counter<<endl;

    free(u);
    return 0;
}
```

My test output:

```
Test 1 (unsorted)
-0.650426
Run took 32114525, total loop: 9205058
Test 1 (sorted)
-0.649237
Run took 40915156, total loop: 4101917
```

Comment: What build flags are you using?

Comment: The test might be memory bound on the outer loop when fetching parts of `u`. It mighy not matter how much faster the inner loop runs.

Comment: Are the `sample` calls expected to produce very different results for the two versions?

Comment: Hello, Francois! Memory fetching bottleneck sounds likely. I've tried Perf utility  on my program. Here's its output :
 Performance counter stats for './sample':

       374 827 383      cycles                                                      
           664 657      cache-references                                            
           619 055      cache-misses              #   93,139 % of all cache refs    

 I guess this high rate of cache-misses means something (what exactly?). So, how can this bottleneck be fooled around?

Comment: Francois, on a second thought it's not the outer loop. When I repeat the test with the first pair of arrays (i.e. add one more for loop  like "Test 1 (unsorted)" after "Test 1 (sorted)"), the loop execution time goes back. You see, I'm more surprised to see that the execution time increases for the sorted array than that it's not significantly reduced.

Comment: @AndreiZorine Use the `@` before someone's name to make sure the site notifies them of your message.

Comment: @AndreiZorine Please share the build flags you are using.

Comment: @AndreiZorine A cache miss means that a value you need was not in the cache at the time you needed it. A high rate of misses means that you will frequently have to fetch values from memory which very very slow in terms of CPU time and relative to cache hits.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I compile with 'g++ -o sample -g -O0  -v main.cpp'. And I tried -O2 and -O3

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Exactly! The point was that the sorted version was expected to be essentialy faster that the unordered version while your tests have them with same execution time! Moreover, srand doesn't matter because the it's used only once to initialize the u array (and your version doesnt seem to initialize the array at all).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Change the sum += ... line in each function into sum+=sample(p,x,5,runif(),&counter);  and behold! The sorted version execution time is longer than the unsorted version time! :(

Comment: @AndreiZorine That might be because the test I linked had UB. If I initialize the array for each test, then [sorted runs slower](http://quick-bench.com/wujClNJrZJvbJZIJXFPUgYiu9QI).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, it does! But it isn't supposed to! On the average, the for loop with unsorted p array does more iterations. So, why is it still faster???

Comment: I ran it under `perf stat -ddd` and it says the sorted version incurs 50% more branch misses.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, it's the trade-off between compiler's capabilities and the complexity of the algorthm. The 5-element array was too small for the benefits of ordering to show off and the CPU mechanisms were overtaking this gain. It was only after initializing all arrays (`p`, `x`, `p1`, and `x1`) with more data (circa 30 elements) that the sorted array generates the output times faster than an unsorted array.

The proof (a new `main()` function):

```
int main()
{
  // R: p1 <- dhyper( 0:30, 100, 200, 30)
  double p[]  = {2.365460e-06, 4.149930e-05, 3.463503e-04, 1.831185e-03, 6.890624e-03,
         1.965600e-02, 4.420738e-02, 8.049383e-02, 1.209103e-01, 1.519072e-01,
         1.612748e-01, 1.458034e-01, 1.128909e-01, 7.516566e-02, 4.315606e-02,
         2.139919e-02, 9.167998e-03, 3.391496e-03, 1.081390e-03, 2.963208e-04,
         6.947942e-05, 1.385778e-05, 2.332594e-06, 3.278979e-07, 3.795897e-08,
         3.550624e-09, 2.612802e-10, 1.454013e-11, 5.743665e-13, 1.433179e-14,
         1.695929e-16};
  double x[]  = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
         20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30};
  // R: p1.sort( p1, decreasing=TRUE, index=TRUE)
  double p1[] = {1.612748e-01, 1.519072e-01, 1.458034e-01, 1.209103e-01, 1.128909e-01,
         8.049383e-02, 7.516566e-02, 4.420738e-02, 4.315606e-02, 2.139919e-02,
         1.965600e-02, 9.167998e-03, 6.890624e-03, 3.391496e-03, 1.831185e-03,
         1.081390e-03, 3.463503e-04, 2.963208e-04, 6.947942e-05, 4.149930e-05,
         1.385778e-05, 2.365460e-06, 2.332594e-06, 3.278979e-07, 3.795897e-08,
         3.550624e-09, 2.612802e-10, 1.454013e-11, 5.743665e-13, 1.433179e-14,
         1.695929e-16};
  double x1[] = {10,  9, 11,  8, 12,  7, 13,  6, 14, 15,  5, 16,  4, 17,  3, 18,  2, 19,
         20,  1, 21,  0, 22, 23, 24,  25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30};

  double sum;
  unsigned long counter;

#define NN 1000000
  double *u;
  u = (double*)calloc(NN, sizeof(double));
  if(u==NULL) perror("Not enough mem!");
  srand(5647892);
  for (int i=0; i<NN; i++) u[i]=runif();

  int sz = sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0]);

  cout << "Test 1 (unsorted)" << endl;
  sum=0.0; counter = 0;
  srand(5647892);
  auto begt = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  for(int i=0; i<NN; i++) sum+=sample(p,x,sz,u[i], &counter);
  auto endt = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  auto elapsed = endt - begt;
  cout<<sum/double(NN)<<endl<<"Run took "<<elapsed.count()<<", total loop: "<< counter<<endl;

  cout << "Test 1 (sorted)" << endl;
  sum=0.0; counter = 0;
  srand(5647892);
  begt = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  for(int i=0; i<NN; i++) sum+=sample(p1,x1,sz,u[i],&counter);
  endt = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  elapsed = endt - begt;
  cout<<sum/double(NN)<<endl<<"Run took "<<elapsed.count()<<", total loop: "<< counter<<endl;

  free(u);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample running times:

```
Test 1 (unsorted)
10.0038
Run took 23076167, total loop: 10003850
Test 1 (sorted)
10.0047
Run took 14010650, total loop: 3442722
```

Comment: Glad you found it.